# High resolution satellite

Tags: data, remote-sensing, image, resolution, satellite

Can any one tell me from where I can buy commercial High resolution Satellite images for Biodiversity research ? I need some websites that sells these kind of images ?

Comment: What spatial resolution are you looking for, what geographic coverage, what sort of repeat time, and what is your budget :D. This will help people to answer, as there are global sources, regional sources and national sources.

Comment: And welcome to GIS SE. You will get better answers with more specific questions, was what I was trying to say.

Comment: Thanks John, I just want to know where I can buy these kinds of HR images, as there are different companies when I do search on internet.

Comment: Do you think about take your own photos with drone or some kind of uav for specifi places?

Answer (score 3):

Two of the best commercial high resolution multispectral products available are Worldview-2 and Worldview-3.  These sensors are commonly used for natural resources and biodiversity applications.  You can learn more about these products [here](http://www.satimagingcorp.com/).  Another more cost efficient option is to use RapidEye medium resolution imagery ([details](http://blackbridge.com/rapideye/)).  Of course, if your budget allows you can acquire LiDAR data for your study area.  LiDAR in combination with multispectral data will allow you to make predictions based on structural and spectral properties.

Comment: Also you can use GeoEye (spatial resolution 0.5 m, 4 bands)

Comment: @Pau, GeoEye may be useful in combination with LiDAR.  Although the spectral resolution on GeoEye alone limits its application in biodiversity research.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is the list of some high resolution imagery providers and resellers:

1. https://www.digitalglobe.com/
2. https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/
3. http://www.intelligence-airbusds.com/en/4871-browse-and-order
4. https://www.planet.com/
5. http://catalog.sovzond.ru/
6. http://search.kosmosnimki.ru/
7. http://www.imagesatintl.com/high-resolution-satellite-imagery/
8. http://www.si-imaging.com/purchase/

Answer (score 1):

The biggest data provider is [DigitalGlobe](https://www.digitalglobe.com/). They also have the arguably best satellite (WorldView-3). You can buy directly from them, or you can go through one of the many resellers. A price of around 16$ per sqkm is usual for 4 spectral bands and 20$ for 8-bands - [link to list with prices](http://www.landinfo.com/satellite-imagery-pricing.html).

A slightly cheaper option is Pleiades and SPOT data from [Airbus D&S](http://www.geo-airbusds.com/geostore/). Only 4 bands available.

Furthermore, you can also go for RapidEye. A 5 meter resolution is still good for many projects, but the level of detail is not near that available from DigitalGlobe or Airbus.